# How do custom modules get imported using webpack + ES6?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I am converting my ES6 AngularJS application to use webpack for all its vendor JS libraries as well as its own business logic. In my code I have something like:

`angular.module('company.web.productA', [..., 'company.web.core'])`

where `company.web.core` is another angular module that gets bundled with webpack.  Right now my application isn't erroring out at all but it also isn't loading. I just see a blank screen. I think the issue is that I don't have the `company.web.core` module loaded and therefore the application doesn't bootstrap properly.

Am I expected to do some kind of `import` statement in order to get my custom modules? So far I have only used `import` to pull in 3rd party npm packages and individual component files but how do I go about importing an entire module?

There is a chance I am thinking about this wrong and I'm not required to do this, so any advice or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting confused with AngularJS Modules and ES6 Modules.

AngularJS Modules are standalone AngularJS Features. They can be used on their own or they can be used in another AngularJS Modules.

To import them, you just do what you do with a TypeScript Module. Here's a [Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-8r5sfr?file=home%2Findex.js) for your reference.

Consider HomeModule for example in this StackBlitz Project. It's present in the home folder. The home folder also has an index.js file which has HomeModule as the default exported member.

And then it is imported inside the app.js file like this:

```
import './home'
```

Please feel free to click on export to download the project zip and have a look at the configuration for a better understanding.